# can't pass value from form to php page

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to pass a variable from a number input to a php page.

HTML CODE

```
<input type="number" class="count count-disco" name="quantita_cialda_disco" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0">
```

[image: image 1]

PHP and JQUERY CODE

```
$quantita_cialda_disco = $_POST['quantita_cialda_disco'];

echo $quantita_cialda_disco;


$('.count-disco').prop('disabled', true);
                $(document).on('click','.plus-disco',function(){
                    $('.count-disco').val(parseInt($('.count-disco').val()) + 1 );
                    if ($('.count-disco').val() == 0) {
                    $('.count-disco').val(1);
                    }
                    calcPrice();
                });

                $(document).on('click','.minus-disco',function(){
                    $('.count-disco').val(parseInt($('.count-disco').val()) - 1 );
                    if ($('.count-disco').val() == 0) {
                    $('.count-disco').val(0);
                    }
                    calcPrice();
               });
```

I manage the number field with + and -, I also attach the jquery.

I really don't understand why I can't pass the value.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your `<form>` tag contain the attribute `method="post"`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, i try with  other variables and  it works

Comment: And the `<input>` tag is inside the `<form>` .... `</form>` tags? Sorry for these questions, but your form code, in the question, is incomplete.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware sorry if I didn't put the whole form, but it's really long. yes, absolutely, it is inside the form tag.

Comment: You can use [the developer tools of your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to see which parameters are submitted by the form.

Comment: Are you trying to initialize the value of this field using the placeholder attribute? Use the value attribute instead (`value="0"` instead of `placeholder="0"`)

Comment: @DPAMonty i try, but i have the same result

Comment: Oh, and I see that you disabled the field. Try to use `readonly="true"` instead. Disabled fields are not included in the parameters collection.

Comment: @DPAMonty solved! thanks, i remove this $('.count-disco').prop('disabled', true);

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('.count-disco').prop('readonly', true);` instead of `$('.count-disco').prop('disabled', true);`. Disabled fields are removed from form parameters when it is submitted.